# Form Recognizer labels not loading

Tags: forms, azure, azure-form-recognizer

My Tags/Labels bar on the right side of screen doesn't work. Its loading all the time. Theres Just spinner.
When I click on adding table tags it works Just to create, but after creation I can't maintain it.
Does anybody has idea what could cause the problem?

Answer (score 0):

I found a solution - there was a problem with visibility of invoices inside of the blob - form recognizer couldn't process one of them and had a problem with labels.

I've changed the sets of invoices and everything worked just fine.